# dealing with bad comments that don't deserve a flag and the commenter never responds

Tags: discussion, comments

How do you deal with this, if it is a problem?

Comment: Can you cite a specific example? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

You have two choices:

1. Flag them anyway. If they don't really deserve it, nothing will happen as far as the site is concerned (because *no one else* will flag them) apart from your secret [flag reliability rating](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/) dropping off a bit. But, you might feel better.
2. Ignore them and get on with your life. This has all the advantages of #1, plus the added bonus of being slightly less work.

Answer (score 5):

(I was bored and wanted to try out OpenOffice Draw)
[image]

As far as them never responding, if you post a reply that adds to the discussion with additions, corrections or alternatives, it doesn't really matter if the person you were replying even *sees* it, nevermind replying.  It will still benefit plenty of other people that come across the discussion.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55670/do-personal-attacks-merit-flagging-comments/55671#55671) might also apply.